# Partial<T> when T is constrained by object shape

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I encountered an error when trying to use `Partial<T>` in this scenario:

```
type WithName = {
    name: string
}

function test<T extends WithName>(x: T) {
    // Error: Type '{ name: "a"; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
    let a: Partial<T> = {
        name: 'a'
    }

    // Error: Type '{ name: "a"; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
    merge<T>(x, {name: 'a'})
}

declare function merge<T>(a: T, b: Partial<T>): T
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgOQIYFtoF4oG8BQURUAdhhAFxQDOwATnCQOb4C+++AZgK4kDGwOAHsSUYBFoAeACpQIAD3EkAJtVgIU5AHwAKeVWkBKPIWIB6M1ACidOkLoHw0AOS5S5KgCJUngNxRWZyg4NRIhYChUamo4JjIAIwAbaGAhMScoZwAFVDpBVESZLWcAOlMiZIjUKhy8uAKiqBwCYlb3TCpnVGdygI5Wi2tbe0dITLcyDqhvPwCgkNJwyOjYhOSxNNAx7Nz8wulistbMOiYIIr0AGjxJykzu1kM2DmUIPkTc6B5+QREoE7OF2qUGk13iNV29X2WkMBiAA)

Is it a typescript limitation?

It works correctly with spread syntax: `{...x, name: 'a'}`, but I want to use a custom merge function.

Comment: Ultimately it's because the caller chooses the type parameter and because properties can themselves be narrowed.  So the caller can pass in a value of type `Larry` defined as `interface Larry {name: "Larry"}` and then `{name: "a"}` is absolutely not a `Partial<Larry>`.  See the linked q/a for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Btw, it turns out that the spread syntax form should also give the same error.

Comment: It probably "should"... TypeScript interprets object spread on generics as being an intersection...  e.g., if `x` is of generic type `X` then `{...x, a: 123}` is seen as being of type `X & {a: number}`, which is unsound when properties get overwritten.  But if this were enforced properly, e.g., `Omit<X, "a"> & {a: number}`, then a lot of real world code would break and it would introduce more problems than it would solve. For better or worse, a provably correct type system isn't one of the design goals of the language.